# CSS - Flexbox ,shrink items

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex box container, with a child element inside. When the screen size shrinks, I want the child to also shrink. Here is my existing code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
 


.child {
    width: 570px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.child {
    flex-basis: 200px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 570px;
}
  
.child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Update number 3. Note this has not flex direction, therefore is column by default:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
  
.child  { 
    background-color: red; 
    width: 800px; 
    height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219419/discussion-on-question-by-nodereact020-css-flexbox-shrink-items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}
 


.child {
    background-color: red; 
    width: 80%; 
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="child"></div>    


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a media query to accomplish what you aim:

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
}

.child  { 
 background-color: red; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 800px;
} 
@media screen and (min-width: 800px){
 .container {
 padding: 0 20px;
 }
 .child {
 width: 800px; 
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Helps alot

Answer (score 0):

Here is one just set the width of the `.container` to `100%` of its container or `body` so when when the body shrinks also the width of `.container` reduced and give the `.child` `50%` of its `width`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. The problem with this solution, Is that I want a set PX value for the child. So it is the same on large screens. However when the screen shrinks, and the content can't fit, thats only when I want it to shrink. Any solutions? Thanks